# Como puedo conocer el estado de colección de datos de FireBase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Hola Estoy trabajando con Android e IOS con firebase , pero nose como llegar a conocer el estado de la recolección de datos (AnalyticsCollections)  o hacer que inicien desde el lanzamiento de firebase.

He intentado este metodo en Android

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value=true/>
```

Pero al iniciar la app me muestra el log:

> D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked.
>   Skipping initialization

y firebase no inicia recolección de datos

Como puedo cambiar esto para que inicie desde el lanzamiento y pueda conocer si estado , si esta recolectado ?

Comment: Vale Gracias  , voy a mejorar la pregunta

Comment: tenes configurado Firebase? funciona algun producto?